# fetchUuidsWithSdp() returning SDPs twice for each device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am writing an Android app (ICS 4.0.3) to discover devices and list their UUIDs.

The app does a bluetooth device discovery and when it finds a device it saves it.  Once the device discovery is complete it goes back through all the devices it saved and does a fetchUUidsWithSdp() and then in a broadcast receiver prints out the UUIDs it finds.

When the app is run I get each two sets of responses each one set contains all the UUIDs on all the devices it discovered.

Is this the way it is supposed to work?

I see in the documentation that:

*If there is an error in getting the SDP records or if the process takes a long time, ACTION_UUID intent is sent with the UUIDs that is currently present in the cache.*

Both sets of responses come pretty quickly but I guess the first could be from cache and the second from the remote device.

The code can be found at http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-discover-and.html.

Comment: have a doubt,? we can able to connect another device using this  getUuids() of paticular device, we can able to connect?(Other devices such as printer, as we cannot install our app to listen) is this possible?